# Setting a User Reference Programmatically in a Rule

Tags: rules, users

Use Case: I have Supervisors creating (authoring) Employee Evaluations and need to give the employees view access to their past evaluations. In the evaluation node I have an existing select list with the employee names that has a key of the employees User ID (in LDAP).

I think that I can create the desired functionality with the References module to create the user reference and then the Node Access User Reference for permissioning.

Problem: I want the supervisor to select the employee name from a select list and then set the user reference programmatically (possible with a Rule that contains a PHP snippet action).

So Far I have tried the following in a Rule for the creation of a new Evaluation (with no success)

```
$username = $node->field_employee_name2[$node->language][0]['value'];
$user = user_load_by_name($username);
$user_id = $user->uid;
$node->field_employee_name_user_[$node->language][0]['uid']=$user_id;
```